# How can I get my UICollectionView to be the same width as my device when using Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout, uicollectionview

I created a `UICollectionView` in the storyboard editor and added it to my (custom) `ViewController`. Like every view controller in storyboard, it says the size is 600x600 and so the `UICollectionView`, which takes up the whole view, is also 600x600.

This is not correct though, as I am writing an iPhone app and so the real dimensions should be 320x568!

Because of this, when I add items to my collection, they are placed off the right side of the screen. For example, I first add a cell with an image in of size 160x213. It is left justified and it takes up exactly the left half of the screen. When I add the next image, there is a huge gap and it appears on the left side, partly cut off. The third image I would expect to appear below the first, but it doesn't appear at all. I believe it is off the right side of the screen. This implies that the size of the `UICollectionView` is 600x600 and not 320x568.

I should mention that I've tried everything I could think of to fix this. For example:

- I tried adjusting the size of the collection view:

  ```
  self.photoCollection.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568);
  ```
- I tried unchecking "Use Size Classes" in the storyboard editor.

It seems to work if I uncheck "Use Auto Layout" but I would like to use auto layout. How do I get this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can set the "Simulated Metrics" of the view in your storyboard like this below. Personally, I prefer using 3.5/4-inch to construct my layout, as with auto layout, i only need to add some constraints to elements and iOS will automatically support the 4.7 and 5 inch screen size.

[image]

2. I think you should google for some "Auto Layout" tutorials, and I don't think its too hard for you to pick up :D. For instance, if you want to set the collection view frame equal to your view frame. You can do it like this

[image]

Feel free to ask any follow up question if your have any, Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! That fix most of my problems but Auto Layout still seems a little confusing. First, I noticed I had to se the vertical space for my UICollectionView to be -64. When it was set to 0, the first cell would not be aligned to the top-left corner but instead offset quite a ways down. I'm assuming this has something to do with the fact that I have a navigation view controller so there is a bar at the top. Still, I don't understand why that affects the collection view.

Comment: Second, my cells (I subclassed from UICollectionViewCell) consist solely of a UIImageView which I want to to fill the whole cell. When I set 4 constraints around the sides to "0", there still is a sizable margin around the image. If I hardcode the size of the cell and the UIImageView to be exactly the same size (the size of the image), there is no margin. I'm using aspect fit.

Comment: Refer to your -64 offset problem, 1. you can take a look to my image1. There is a option on the right hand side bar called "Extend Edges", uncheck the "Under Top Bars". 2. You may also check whether if your view is embedded into a navigation controller :D

Comment: for the cells problem, you can refer to this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights